# sympy.physics.units substitution gives TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to use sympy as a backend for some conversion/math code and ran into this problem.

```py
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.physics import units

type(units.newton) # -> sympy.physics.units.quantities.Quantity

parse_expr('2*Newton').subs({'Newton':units.newton}) # -> 2N
parse_expr('2*newton').subs({'newton':units.newton}) # -> 2N
parse_expr('2*n').subs({'n':units.newton}) # -> 2N
parse_expr('2*N').subs({'N':units.newton}) # -> raises TypeError below
parse_expr('N').subs() # -> raises AttributeError below
parse_expr('N') # -> <function sympy.core.evalf.N(x, n=15, **options)>
```

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Integer' and 'function'`

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'subs'`

It appears sympy substitutes the evalf.N function instead of the provided units.newton . Is there an order of substitution that can be adjusted, or a way to remove the 'N' function from substitution options?

Edit: Verified evalf.N

The evalf.N function is what's used, but keeping if from being used seems to be a problem. Tried using the `.subs(..., global_dict=...)` with no effect on errors.

```
parse_expr('N') is sympify('N') # -> True
sympify('N') is evalf.N # -> True
```

Comment: This particular part seems to be at issue:

    parse_expr('2*N')

But if you use a letter other than capital N, things seem to work. Could this be a bug in sympy, or a feature we're not considering?

Comment: The evalf.N function is what's used, but keeping if from being used seems to be a problem. ```parse_expr('N') is sympify('N') # -> True``` ```sympify('N') is evalf.N # -> True```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation `parse_expr` takes an optional parameter:

```
global_dict : dict, optional

    A dictionary of global variables. By default, this is initialized with 
    from sympy import *; provide this parameter to override this behavior 
    (for instance, to parse "Q & S").
```

`from sympy import *` introduces a function `N` into the global nampespace, which `parse_expr()` is using when it parses the 'N' in your last three examples.

You can redefine 'N' in the global namespace:

```
N = units.newton
parse_expr('2*N')  -> 2*newton
```

If you can't redefine 'N', then make a copy of `globals()`, modify the copy, and pass that to `parse_expr()`:

```
globals_with_units = dict(globals())
globals_with_units['N'] = units.newton

parse_expr('2*N', global_dict=globals_with_units)  -> 2*newton
```

`parse_expr()` also takes a `local_dict` parameter:

```
local_dict : dict, optional

    A dictionary of local variables to use when parsing.
```

It can be used to override the definition of 'N' in the global namespace.

```
parse_expr('2*N', local_dict={'N':units.newton})  -> 2*newton
```

Comment: I'm not using * import, so ```globals()['N']``` raises KeyError. Passing global_dict with or without 'N' as a key didn't seem to change the errors.  ```global_dict={'N':units.newton}``` didn't even work.

Comment: Using ```local_dict``` instead works. Probably an order of precedence result in low level sympy. If you adjust your answer to that instead of global_dict, I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: If you don't provide a globals_dict, `parse_expr()` it uses a dictionary that is initialized like you did do `from sympy import *`.